# Center a div with a known width with unknown window size

Tags: html, css

(Utilizing only css and html for compatibility reasons)

I currently have a menu that I'm including on multiple pages (via object with links targeting parent) and I'm trying to center the div horizontally.  Using the width of 969px set and margins it centers properly but when the window size becomes too small the menu vanishes completely.

Here is the code I've constructed so far:

```
<link href="thestyles.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<div id='themagic'>
<div class='pipe'>|</div>
<a href='./index.html' target="_top"><div id='navbutton'>Home</div></a> <div class='pipe'>|</div> 
<a href='./HH.html' target="_top"><div id='navbutton'>Heroin Hypothesized</div></a> <div class='pipe'>|</div> 
<a href='./PR.html' target="_top"><div id='navbutton'>Pain Relief</div></a> <div     class='pipe'>|</div> 
<a href='./IPF.html' target="_top"><div id='navbutton'>IPF End-Of-Life Care</div></a> <div class='pipe'>|</div> 
<a href='./HAT.html' target="_top"><div id='navbutton'>Heroin Assisted Treatment</div></a> <div class='pipe'>|</div> 
<a href='./Cited.html' target="_top"><div id='navbutton'>Works Cited</div></a> <div class='pipe'>|</div>
</div>
```

As well here is the CSS I've constructed:
(Note I've gone through many different approaches to this, none of which yielded the correct results, so some of this may be "throw away")

```
#nav
{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#themagic{
width:969px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

#navbutton
{
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
    background: #e8edff;
    color: #669;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display:-webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-pack:center;
    -webkit-box-align:center;
    display:-moz-box;
    -moz-box-pack:center;
    -moz-box-align:center;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 15px;
    float:left;
    font-size:75%;
}

#navbutton:hover
{
    background:#D0DAFD;
    color:#333399;
}

.pipe
{
    color:#669;
    float:left;
    padding:15px;
}
```

Comment: I don't see it disappearing if the window size is too small.  I just see that it causes a horizontal scroll bar.

Answer (score 2):

To center a div, just add this css to it

```
#div{
     margin-left:auto;
     margin-right:auto;

}
```

Comment: I have that already in my code, the problem I'm having with this is when the window becomes small the menu vanishes completely.

Answer (score 0):

You have used id `navbutton` times. `ID`s cannot be same. They must be unique.

Use `class` instead.

Try:

```
#themagic{text-align:center;}
.navbutton,.pipe{display:inline-block;} /* remove float:left*/
```

NOTE:

`inline-block` adds white-space between elements. To remove white space, write elements on same line instead of writing them on separate lines.

Change

```
<div class='pipe'>|</div>
<a href='./index.html' target="_top"><div id='navbutton'>Home</div></a> <div class='pipe'>|</div>..
```

to

```
<div class='pipe'>|</div><a href='./index.html' target="_top"><div class='navbutton'>Home</div></a><div....
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/fM79N/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply try changing `#themagic` to a fluid width, for example 100%.

http://jsfiddle.net/eshellborn/AdLcx/